# How is preferable to allocate this array?

Tags: c++

I have two alternatives:

```
class X{
int* x;
int size = ...;
void create() { 
    x = new int[size];
    use();
    delete [] x;
}
void use() {//use array}
};
```

or:

```
class X{
int size = ...;
void create(){ 
    int x[size];
    use(x);
}
void use(int arg[]) {//use arg}
};
```

which is better?

Comment: If you use the first option you must not forget to `delete[]` at the end. Ideally you should use `std::vector` anyway.

Comment: Neither. In C++, `new` is bad, naked pointers are worse, and array-`new` is outright immoral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option 3 is better, using `std::vector`.

```
class X{
    std::vector<int> x;
    int size; // = ...; <-- the "=" part is illegal in C++03
    void create() { 
        x.resize(size);
        use();
    } 
};
```

Also, your second snippet is illegal, C++ doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: The `int size =` is legal C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Second alternative is not working, since size is not a constant value.

First alternative misses the destructor, where the deallocation (`delete[] x`) should be performed.

I suggest a third alternative: use `std::vector<int>` class for x. You don't need explicit destructor for deallocating the memory, and it is generally safer to use than C-style arrays.

Comment: Well, he deallocates the array in the `create` method, where the allocation is performed.